# Entity Framework Code first generating weird database schema when using interfaces

Tags: interface, mapping, associations, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have following Classes and interfaces..

```
 public interface ITaggable
    {
         ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }

 public class Book :ITaggable
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)] 
        public Guid BookId { get;set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get; set;}
    }

public class Pen:ITaggable
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
        public Guid PenId { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get; set;}
    }

public class Tag
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)] 
        public Guid TagId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ITaggable> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

For the above model it generates the following table structure

Book -->
BookId , Title , Author

Pen -->
PenId , Color

Tag -->
TagId , Name ,BookBookId , PenPenId

And when i insert the following data

```
            Tag tag = new Tag();
            tag.Name = "Stationary";

            Book b1 = new Book();
            b1.Title = "Head first c#";
            b1.Author = "Betty";
            b1.Tags = new List<Tag>() { tag };

            Book b2 = new Book();
            b2.Title = "Head first Java";
            b2.Author = "Katty";
            b2.Tags = new List<Tag>() { tag };

            Pen p = new Pen();
            p.Color = "Red";
            p.Tags = new List<Tag>() { tag };

            context.Books.Add(b1);
            context.Books.Add(b2);
            context.Pens.Add(p);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

It does not insert the Tag data for the second book

What i want to accomplish is that i want to implement a three table tagging system
[shown here](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html)  adhering to my class structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will not store the tag info for one of the books because your tag instance can be associated only with single book. That would require your many-to-many relation between `Book` and `Tag` but your relation is one-to-many. Relation between `Pen` and `Tag` is also one-to-many. That is clearly visible by foreign keys in `Tag` table.

The problem is that `ICollection<ITaggable> Items` is skipped by EF code first - code first doesn't work with interfaces. You must define your Tag as:

```
public class Tag
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)] 
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pen> Pens { get; set; }
}
```

This will map many-to-many between `Book` and `Tag` and many-to-many between `Pen` and `Tag`. If you want also collection of `ITaggable` you can expose another property concatenating `Books` and `Pens`.

If you really want one-to-many relation then you cannot expect that tag will be associated with multiple books and in such case your `Tag` entity should look like:

```
public class Tag
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)] 
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public virtual Pen Pen { get; set; }
}
```

Again you can create `Items` as computed property. Any combination of relation should be obvious from these examples.

Edit:

If you don't want to expose navigation properties in Tag you must use fluent-api:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pen> Pens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                    .HasMany(b => b.Tags)
                    .WithMany();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pen>()
                    .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
                    .WithMany();
    }
}
```

Further fluent api reference can be found on [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx) but it is not up to data (it is for CTP5).

Comment: So for each class(which needs tagging) i add in my system i'll have to add  (public virtual ICollection<NewClass> NewClasses {get;set;}) in my Tag class..i think that will be a not so good design....are there any other workaround

Comment: i can use a base class instead of an interface

Comment: If you want access from `Tag` to tagged classes there is no other solution. You can omit these navigation properties in `Tag` at all but you will have to use fluent api to map your relations and you will not able to access related entities from `Tag`. Base class will introduce inheritance mapping to your model which leads to other consequences.

Comment: ok..can you give me any reference to flent api links where i can find similar solutions...

Comment: How are your tables defined now?

Comment: I just tested exactly your insert code with mapping changes I proposed (removed navigation property from `Tag` and fluent mapping to define many-to-many relation) and it works. I have two records in `BookTags` table and one in `PenTags` (junction tables created for many-to-many mapping).

Comment: okay...Actually i hadnt removed the navigation property from Tag...and now it is working as you've said...Just one more question...How will i get "all the Items(Book, Pen, etc etc) for a particular tag"...Thank you so much :)

Comment: If you removed navigation properties from Tag the answer is badly. You must create queries for each item and union them.

Comment: But there is no other solution other than removing the navigation property